# If `apt` is just a more "user-friendly" variant of `apt-get` that "automatically satisfies dependency strings", why does `apt satisfy` work?

Tags: debian, apt

Unfortunately, Google Bard does not list citations, so I'll just quote the result:

> Sure. APT and apt-get are both command-line tools for managing software packages on Debian-based Linux distributions. They are both based on the APT library, but they have different strengths and weaknesses.
> APT is a more user-friendly tool that is designed for end users. It provides a number of features that make it easier to install, upgrade, and remove packages, such as the ability to automatically resolve package dependencies and the ability to use a graphical package manager.
> apt-get is a more powerful tool that is designed for system administrators. It provides a wider range of options than APT, such as the ability to install packages from remote repositories and the ability to manage package groups.
> In general, APT is a good choice for end users who want a simple and easy-to-use tool for managing software packages. apt-get is a good choice for system administrators who need a more powerful tool with more options.
> Here is a table that summarizes the key differences between APT and apt-get:
> Feature APT apt-get User-friendliness More user-friendly Less user-friendly Power Less powerful More powerful Options Fewer options More options Target audience End users System administrators
> Ultimately, the best tool for you will depend on your individual needs and preferences. If you are an end user who wants a simple and easy-to-use tool, then APT is a good choice. If you are a system administrator who needs a more powerful tool with more options, then apt-get is a good choice.

If I am understanding this description correctly, one would assume that `apt` satisfies dependency strings automatically without explicit user intervention.  However, if that is the case, why does `apt satisfy` result in additional packages being installed?

EDIT: Per comments received, here are some additional details:

- I installed `adb` using `apt install android-sdk-platform-tools`
- I ran `apt satisfy android-sdk-platform-tools`
- Here is the output from the latter:

```
root@penguin:~# apt satisfy android-sdk-platform-tools
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  android-libetc1 android-libext4-utils android-libsparse android-libunwind android-libziparchive android-sdk-platform-tools dmtracedump etc1tool f2fs-tools fastboot fonts-liberation graphviz hprof-conv libann0
  libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libgvpr2 liblab-gamut1 libpathplan4 p7zip p7zip-full sqlite3
0 upgraded, 25 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5,906 kB of archives.
After this operation, 21.5 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
```

- Unfortunately, I had already closed the terminal session for the initial install before I even created this post, but I don't recall seeing any errors or anything out of the norm.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @Community To clarify: according to the quoted description, if I use `apt install someapp`, it should automatically satisfy the dependency strings for `someapp`.  So why is it that `apt satisfy someapp` can result in new packages being installed?

Comment: What does the wall of text quoted in the middle have to do with the question? (And if it does have some relevance, how much of it is actually relevant?) What's the actual problem you have? What commands were you running, what output did you get?

Comment: @muru The quoted text was what resulted from Google Bard when I searched "apt vs apt-get".  Specifically, I have ADB installed through `apt`, but when I ran `apt satisfy android-sdk-platform-tools`, I received a prompt to install 24 new packages.

Comment: Installed it how? Which 24 new packages? What does some garbage dump for "apt vs apt-get" have to do that?

Comment: There's no real "problem" per-se, it's just that this had occurred and immediately subsequent to the occurrence, I happened to search the difference between `apt` and `apt-get`, and that led to my question out of academic curiosity.

Comment: @muru These: "The following NEW packages will be installed:
  android-libetc1 android-libext4-utils android-libsparse android-libunwind android-libziparchive android-sdk-platform-tools dmtracedump etc1tool f2fs-tools fastboot fonts-liberation graphviz hprof-conv libann0
  libcdt5 libcgraph6 libgts-0.7-5 libgts-bin libgvc6 libgvpr2 liblab-gamut1 libpathplan4 p7zip p7zip-full sqlite3"
It was installed using `apt install android-sdk-platform-tools`.

Comment: Add that output to the question please, using code formatting: https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help#code. Also add the output you had for `apt install android-sdk-platform-tools`.

Comment: @muru I'll edit the OP with the new packages, but unfortunately I already closed the terminal session for the `apt install` prior to posting the OP.

Comment: `adb` is in the eponymous package, are you sure you installed `android-sdk-platform-tools`?

Comment: Since you didn’t use `apt-get`, what does the comparison have to do with your question?

Comment: @Arctiic you should check the `apt` logs to see what you actually installed (it should also show what command you actually ran), because it's installing `android-sdk-platform-tools`, clearly showing it's not already installed

Comment: @StephenKitt I'm likely misinterpreting something fundamental in the lexical vernacular usage, but when I read that `apt` "automatically satisfies dependency strings", it naturally led me to question why an application installed through `apt` would subsequently result in additional packages prompted to be installed with the `satisfy` option.  `apt-get` wasn't directly involved, it's just the verbatim search term I used that generated the quoted information, albeit as you've pointed out it is apparently misleading.

Comment: `apt install foo` and `apt satisfy foo` produce the same result, which is why I suspect that you’re mis-remembering — I think you ran `apt install adb` (directly or indirectly), not `apt install android-sdk-platform-tools`.

Answer (score 4):

The answer you got from Bard is woefully misleading. There are so many inaccuracies and errors in the quote given in your question that there isn’t much point trying to correct it.

`apt` and `apt-get` provide pretty much the same features; in particular, they resolve dependencies in the same way, they both handle remote repositories, and they support the same options.

`apt satisfy` is the same as `apt-get satisfy`. It resolves dependency constraints as they would be written in a source package’s build dependency description, and as such is mostly useful for package developers. Typically, it’s useful when developing a new package, or adding build dependency information to an existing package; in such scenarios, the simpler `apt build-dep` command can’t be used to resolve the package’s build dependencies (because the metadata isn’t available in a repository), and `apt satisfy` can be used instead.

The output you got from `apt satisfy android-sdk-platform-tools` indicates that the package *isn’t* installed. `adb` is shipped in its own `adb` package, not `android-sdk-platform-tools`; I suspect that you installed `adb`, not `android-sdk-platform-tools`, which is why `apt satisfy` wants to install more packages. Both these packages depend on `android-sdk-platform-tools-common` which may have contributed to the confusion.

Comment: I'm of the opinion we should make it clear that Machine Learning statement based questions are just as off-limits as answers. The energy it costs to produce this nonsense (and it *is* nonsense, even in cases where the ML gets things right, because at this point, none of the existing text generators try to *be* right, they are trained solely on *sounding* right in context; no sense, only vocals) is less even than it requires to read it, leave alone correct it. And the energy we spend is human life time and motivation, the energy spend the is hardware seconds.

Comment: Other sites have such rules. For a discussion of a medium sized SE site's approach to ChatGPT-based questions, see my answer [here](https://electronics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9794/64158).

Comment: IMO it's worse than pointless, a complete waste of time to even try to interpret the gibberish from an over-hyped jumped-up markov chain.